# Bootstrap dropdown menu, first element empty

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a simple dropdown menu in Bootstrap 3, but the first element looks empty. I want to delete it but have no idea how. What's more I want do delete empty space between main menu and dropdown. Any ideas how?

Actual look: http://s11.postimg.org/fnbx9j177/Screenshot_from_2016_09_21_10_40_40.png

Code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-delay="175" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Cheers.

Comment: where your html ?

Comment: can you provide us your code please?

Comment: update your html code

Comment: Added, sorry. Still sleeping tho.

Answer (score 0):

As per the code you have provide, it is fine. There is no empty element.

Please check this: [**Live Sample**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QKGxBZ)

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-delay="175" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

If you are having the site live, just update the link. Else post necessary code. It will be helpful to us to help you.

**Edit-1:**

**You forget to close the anchor tag.**

Comment: Site is not uploaded anywhere for now. There's a whole navbar code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0d62039cdf9a408e36578948f34e0784

Comment: close `</a>` anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've fixed this problem myself. There where a missing

```
 </a>
```

tag in line:

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-delay="175" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects
```

Lesson learned: **ALWAYS CLOSE ALL TAGS**

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-delay="175" data-hover="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Projects
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

No Issue I Have Found.Working Fine. Can U Add A Screenshot.

Comment: You SHould Add Those Two JS Script File Above For The Dropdown To Work Fine.